# Cannot read property 'showContent' of undefined when using the ngrx in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

i want to use the ngrx in my project but when i use that it show me this error :

> Cannot read property 'showContent' of undefined

this is my ngrx config :

this is my reducer :

```
export interface State extends fromRoot.State {
    helpDesk: HelpDeskState;
}

export interface HelpDeskState {
    showContent: string;
}

const initialHelpContent: HelpDeskState = {
    showContent: 'null'
}

const getHelpContentFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<HelpDeskState>('helpDesk');
export const showHelpContnt = createSelector(getHelpContentFeatureState, state => state.showContent)


export function reducer(state = initialHelpContent, action): HelpDeskState {

    switch (action.type) {

        case 'CACH_HELP_DESK_CONTENT':
            return {
                ...state,
                showContent: action.payload
            };


        default: state;
    }
}
```

and i creatd the `state` interface for lazy loading :

```
export interface State {
}
```

now when i want to use this  reducer by this code :

```
   constructor(private helpService: HelpService,
    private store: Store<fromHelp.State>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.FetchDate()
  }

  FetchDate(): void {
    this.store.pipe(select(fromHelp.showHelpContnt)).subscribe(data => {
      if (data) {
        this.content = data
      } else {
        this.helpService.GetGelpServiceInfo(this.data.helpDeskType).subscribe(data => {
          this.content = data.result['content'];
          this.store.dispatch({
            type: 'CACH_HELP_DESK_CONTENT',
            payload: this.content
          })
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

show me that error .

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ???**

Comment: You forgot to add the code you wanted to show after `ngrx config`. Anyways, where do you place the `HelpDeskState` in the store? Something is wrong there because your `createFeatureSelector<HelpDeskState>('helpDesk')` returns undefined aka not found.

Comment: i use in my module this config `StoreModule.forFeature('helpDesk',reducer),` and in `app.module` using this config :`StoreModule.forRoot({}),`

Comment: @GunnarB. in top i show you the config

Comment: So basically you define an empty state for the root -> `({})`. This will need the reducers for your root state, basically as entry point. (Probably you want something with `ActionReducerMap`.)

Comment: @GunnarB. when i use this code it worked : `this.store.pipe(select('helpDesk')).subscribe(data => {
      if (data) {
        item = data.helpContent.find(x => x.id == this.data.helpDeskType);
        this.content = item.showContent;
      }
    })`